# adding a new Document method that returns new computed style

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to add a new `Document` method?
I try researching this on google but it only shows how to make your own js object and add a method on it.
This is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
document.prototype.atvalue = function      atvalue(arg)
{
var newType = window.getComputedStyle(this,  null).getPropertyValue(arg);
return newType;
};
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p style="font-size: 100px"> help </p>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why do you want to modify the Document's prototype?

Comment: You have to add it to `Document.prototype` instead of `document.prototype`.

Comment: document doesn't have style, so getComputedStyle will fail

Comment: No, Im not modifying the Documents Prototype. I just want to know if i can add another prototype to the the javascript document.

Comment: you want to add to `document` - then add to document, don't add to document.prototype because that doesn't exist, as document is an instance of Document, and it's Document that has the prototype? and your code will still fail because `document` isn't an Element and has no style, so getComputedStyle will still fail

Comment: Ok, now i know why my code fails to work..

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
SomeConstructorFunction.prototype.foo = something;
```

Then `foo` will be a property of instances of that function:

```
var something = new SomeConstructorFunction();
something.foo();
```

`document` is not a constructor function.

If you want to add a property to an object then … just add it to that object:

```
document.foo = something;
```

Comment: Can you give me some example of "SomeConstructorFunction"?

Comment: `function SomeConstructorFunction() {}`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create a document prototype function, but you can create a custom document method by:

```
document.something = function(){};
```

and by calling it:

```
document.something();
```